# Right way to catch slug1/slug2/slug3 page with Regex?

Tags: regex, nested-urls

I am trying to use this Re-pattern `r'\({2}.+?\){2}'`
to catch a `((slug1/slug2/slug3 someword))` expression from text.

It gives me the whole expression itself,i.e `'((slug1/slug2/slug3 someword))'`. Then I parse it using `Python:split` it to get `slug1/slug2/slug3` and `someword` separately.

How can I get the same using pure Regex pattern with groups.
What pattern should be?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming slugs can't contain whitespace:

```
\({2}(\S*)\s(.*?)\){2}
```

More explicitly:

```
\({2}  # two literal '(' characters
(\S*)  # any number of non-whitespace characters, captured in group 1
\s     # any whitespace character
(.*?)  # any number of characters, reluctantly, captured in group 2
\){2}  # two literal ')' characters
```

So `slug1/slug2/slug3` will be in group 1 and `someword` will be in group 2.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this regex:

```
/([\w\/]+) (\w+)/
```

It evaluates correctly using this command:

```
perl -e '$a="((slug1/slug2/slug3 someword))"; if ($a =~ /([\w\/]+) (\w+)/) {print "$1 $2"}'
```

Comment: Depending on OP's use-case, you might need to add the parens (e.g. if they're running the regex on a file with lots of other text they don't want matched).

Comment: correct :) it would be nice if the author gave us more insight in the structure of the text

Comment: text could be anything,it will be used for user input field.

Comment: But will the structure of the text always contain two opening parenthesis and two closing parenthesis? Put it differently, given `((slug1/slug2/slug3 someword))`, which parts will changes? Only `slug1/slug2/slug3 someword`? Or also the `((` and `))`?

Comment: ok,got ya. Well, the text will be always with 2 open and 2 closed parenthesis. Only slug1/slug2/slug3 someword will change.

Comment: Good, then beerbajay's and my answer work right? You can accept either of our answers if you think it answers your question and/or upvote answers which you deem helpful.